# Program crashes everytime i use KeyEvent.VK_AT

Tags: java, keyevent

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_AT);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_AT);
```

In my program i need to type in email with keyevents but everytime i use VK_AT my program crashes, other keyevents work fine.

Comment: Press VK_SHIFT, press VK_4, release in reverse order ;)

Comment: (Or what the number is for @, don't have a keyboard at hand :P)

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I had to use VK_SHIFT and VK_2 to make it work.